# Image saved in daatabase but not uploading on the page

Tags: php, database, pdo

Hello recenty i made a project for products, while the CRUD works just fine and adds the products nam,e description, price and image_url into the database when it gets the information only the image is not uploading.Does anyone have a idea what have i forgotten.

Here is my code

productscontroller.php

```
<?php
include_once 'productRepository.php';
include_once 'product.php';

if(isset($_POST['addBtn'])){
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['description']) || empty($_POST['price']) ||
    empty($_POST['image_url'])){
        echo "Fill all fields!";
    }else{
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $image_url = $_POST['image_url'];
        $id = uniqid();


        $product  = new Product($id,$name,$description,$price,$image_url);
        $productRepository = new ProductRepository();

        $productRepository->insertProduct($product);


    }
}
?>
```

productsRepository.php

```
<?php
include_once 'productsdbconnection.php';
include_once 'product.php';

class ProductRepository {
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $conn = new DatabaseConnection();
        $this->connection = $conn->startConnection();
    }

    function insertProduct($product) {
        $conn = $this->connection;

        $id = $product->getId();
        $name = $product->getName();
        $description = $product->getDescription();
        $price = $product->getPrice();
        $image_url = $product->getImage_url();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO products (id, name, description, price, image_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute([$id, $name, $description, $price, $image_url]);
            echo "<script> alert('The product has been registered successfully!'); </script>";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function getAllProducts() {
        $conn = $this->connection;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products"; 

        $statement = $conn->query($sql);
        $products = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $products;
    }

    function getProductById($id) {
        $conn = $this->connection;
    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?"; 
    
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([$id]); 
    
        $product = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
        return $product;
    }
    
    function updateProduct($id, $name, $description, $price, $image_url){
        $conn = $this->connection;
    
        $sql = "UPDATE products SET name=?, description=?, price=?, image_url=? WHERE id=?";
    
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
        $statement->execute([$name, $description, $price, $image_url, $id]);
    
        echo "<script>alert('Update successfuly'); </script>";
    }
    

    function deleteProduct($id){
        $conn = $this->connection;

        $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id=?";

        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute([$id]);

        echo "<script>alert('Deleted successfuly'); </script>";
    } 
}
?>
```

products.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a23437b52f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/banner.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/second-banner.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/paragraf-banner.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/flexbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/howitworks.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/blog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/products.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/productSub.css">
</head>
<style>
       @media screen and (max-width:1215px) {
        .productSubCard{
            width:30%;
        }
       }
       @media screen and (max-width:879px) {
        .productSubCard{
            width:48%;
        }
       }
       @media screen and (max-width:660px) {
        .productSubCard{
            width:60%;
        }
       }
       @media screen and (max-width:530px) {
        .productSubCard{
            width: 70%;
        }
       }
       @media screen and (max-width:430px) {
        .productSubCard{
            width: 80%;
        }
       }
    </style>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logoHolder">
            <a class="logo" href="index.php"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            <a href="howitworks.php">How it Works</a>
            <a href="products.php">Products</a>
            <a href="aboutUs.php">About Us</a>
            <a href="supportus.php">Support Us</a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-auth">
            <a class="signIn" href="login.php">Log In</a>
            <a class="register" href="resgister.php"> Register</a>
        </div>


        <div  class="hamburger-menu">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="productsSub">
        <div class="productSubHeader">
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <div class="productsLine"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="productSubCards">
    <?php
    include_once 'productRepository.php';

    $productRepo = new ProductRepository();
    $products = $productRepo->getAllProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<div class="productSubCard">';
        echo '<form method="post" action="add_to_cart.php">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="' . $product['id'] . '">';

        echo '<div class="productSubCard-up">';
        echo '<div class="productImage" style="background-image: url(' . $product['image_url'] . ');"></div>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="productSubCard-down">';
        echo '<div class="cardTitleS">';
        echo '<p>' . $product['name'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="cardDescription">';
        echo '<p>' . $product['description'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="cardPrice">';
        echo '<p>' . $product['price'] . '$</p>';

        echo '<div class="addToCart">';
        echo '<p class="plus">+</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerUp">
            <div class="footerLogo"></div>
            <div class="socials">
                <p class="contact">Contact Us :</p>
                <div class="socialMedia">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="footer-links">
            <div class="footerLink">
                <p class="footerLink-title">What is Metaverse?</p>
                <a href="">Virtual Reality (VR)</a>
                <a href="">Augmented Reality (AR)</a>
                <a href="">Digital World</a>
                <a href="">Community</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="footerLink">
                <p class="footerLink-title">Blog</p>
                <a href="">Metaverse</a>
                <a href="">How it Works</a>
                <a href="">Latest News</a>
                <a href="">Our Blog</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="footerLink">
                <p class="footerLink-title">About Us</p>
                <a href="">Products</a>
                <a href="">Who We Are</a>
                <a href="">Our Story</a>
                <a href="">The Metaverse Journey</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="footerLink">
                <p class="footerLink-title">Support</p>
                <a href="">Get Help</a>
                <a href="">Customer Support</a>
                <a href="">Assistance Center</a>
                <a href="">Reach Out to Our Support Team</a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="footerLink">
                <p class="footerLink-title">Get In touch</p>
                <a href="">Get in Touch with Us</a>
                <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                <a href="">Reach Out to Us</a>
                <a href="">How to Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the source in the browser, what does it say for the `productImage` div?

Comment: I can see that you save an image URL, but I don't see any code which actually uploads a file, if that's your intention. Also please just provide a [mre] of the issue, without anything irrelevant such as menus and css etc. See also [ask]

Comment: the class of the productImage div its emty if thats what youre asking

Comment: Does the `image_url` have a value in the database? It sounds like it might be empty.

Comment: How are you uploading the image exactly?

Comment: Yes the image_url has a VARCHAR value wich stores the image file like image.jpg

Comment: OK. So which image is that supposed to link to? Again, it doesn't seem like you've written any code which would actually allow the user to upload a picture. All they can do is type in a name

Comment: Thanks for the info I added the code wich alows the user to upload the picture and now its working